# AEM Touch UI RTE multifield default table not appearing

Tags: aem, rich-text-editor, sling, aem-6, crx

I have a multifield which has table. This table is enabled throught RTE

```
<table
   jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
   sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog/richtext"
   useFixedInlineToolbar="true"
   fieldDescription="Enter two data in a row"
   fieldLabel="Enter the Data"                                                  
   name="./table">
```

This is inside a multifield

```
sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/multifield"
```

The thing is when I click add, the RTE text area should have a 3x2 table ready as it was previously(specifically, rows=2, columns=3, width=100%)

When I put the below :

```
value="<table cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' border='1' width='100%'> <tbody> <tr> <td> </td> <td> </td> <td> </td> </tr> <tr> <td> </td> <td> </td> <td> </td> </tr> </tbody> </table>"
```

and build my project, the node doesn't have the value attribute.
If I put

```
value="Some default text"
```

And build it, then value attribute will be present in the table node in the component and the RTE text area will have "Some default text"

BUT

If I directly edit that value in the node as the "...", then the default 3x2 table will come. But it won't come in build when I put it in the XML but the "Some Default Text" will come in the build in the XML

I tried cq:template but I don't know how many tables will be added, so I can't create item0, item1 nodes early.

I have also tried @Default in the Sling model field of table with

```
@Inject
    @Default(values="<table cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' border='1' width='100%'> <tbody> <tr> <td> </td> <td> </td> <td> </td> </tr> <tr> <td> </td> <td> </td> <td> </td> </tr> </tbody> </table>")
    private String table;
```

What should I do ? Thanks in advance.

[image: table node in the CRXDE]